# Find sum of ascii values in a byte[] - c#

Tags: c#, ascii

I want to find the sum of ascii values of string. How to do it?

```
   string value = "9quali52ty3";
  // Convert the string into a byte[].
  byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```

I'am getting output as 57 113 117 97 108 105 53 50 116 121 51.
Now I want to find the sum of above ascii : `57+113+117+97+108+53+50+116+121+51`

Comment: Cast them to int then sum in foreach or sum aggregation with linq

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value).Sum()`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this,

```
string value = "9quali52ty3";
// Convert the string into a byte[].
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
int total = 0;
Array.ForEach(asciiBytes, delegate (byte i) { total += i; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them using a foreach loop

```
    string value = "9quali52ty3";
    // Convert the string into a byte[].
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);

    int total = 0;

    foreach (var i in asciiBytes)
    {
        total += i;
    }
```